# Blocking waiting for file lock on package cache

Tags: jenkins, rust, fedora, rust-cargo

since yesterday evening (16/11/2023 - maybe there was some update) my Jenkins gets stuck with `Blocking waiting for file lock on package cache` on any cargo command (besides fmt).

I have updated the K8s the Jenkins runs on to the latest version, rebuild the Docker image to the latest version of fedora and cargo, and still I get the same issue. This happens on all jobs, even those that worked before (with the same agent image). Locally, I can build without issue.

Steps tried to fix the issue:

1. `cargo clean`
2. `pkill` (doesn't make sense though because it's using a fresh image)
3. remove the lock

It should be said, that I cannot fully flush ~/.cargo, as the image is registered with a private registry

```
# Start with the Fedora image
FROM fedora:latest

# Install basic utilities like curl and gcc.
RUN dnf install -y curl gcc

# Install Rust nightly using rustup
RUN curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh -s -- -y
ENV CARGO_HOME=/root/.cargo
ENV PATH="$CARGO_HOME/bin:${PATH}"
RUN rustup component add rustfmt && \
    rustup component add clippy

# Set the working directory in the container to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Install SSL libraries and other dependencies
RUN dnf install -y openssl-devel git unzip libheif-devel libheif

# Set up Cargo to use crabby
RUN echo -e "[registries.crabby]\nindex = \"https://github.com/.../crab-index-table\"\n[net]\ngit-fetch-with-cli = true" > $CARGO_HOME/config

# Git configurations
RUN git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600' && \
    git config --global user.name "Jenkins Agent" && \
    git config --global user.email "jenkins@soooooooojenkins.io"

# Install protoc
ENV PB_REL="https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases"
RUN curl -LO $PB_REL/download/v3.15.8/protoc-3.15.8-linux-x86_64.zip && \
    unzip protoc-3.15.8-linux-x86_64.zip -d protoc3
ENV PATH=$PATH:/app/protoc3/bin


COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Not really sure about the fedora tag